# Replacing empty lists with a value

Tags: list, haskell, replace

I have a function that returns a list like this:

```
[ [1, 2, 3], [], [5], [5,6], []]
```

But I want to replace the empty lists with 0, so that it looks like this

```
[ [1, 2, 3], [0], [5], [5,6], [0]]
```

So far I have tried `filter` and `map` with little success. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is the code in question:

```
knightPlace:: [Int] -> [[Int]]
knightPlace n = makeboard n

    where
    makeboard n =  [x | i<-[0..(length n -1 )], x <- [checkPos i]]
    -- checkPos add zero
    checkPos i = [j+1 | j<-[0..(length n -1 )], queenFilter n i j]
    -- filters all rows, cols and diags, also knights
    queenFilter n i j = and [n!!(i) == 0 && n!!(k) /=(j+1) && (n!!(k)==0 || (abs(n!!(k)-(j+1))/=abs(i-k))) && (n!!(k)==0 ||not( ((abs(i-k)==2)&& (abs(n!!(k)-(j+1))==1)) ||((abs(i-k)==1)&& (abs(n!!(k)-(j+1))==2))))       | k<-[0..(length n - 1)] ]
```

Called like

```
 knightPlace [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `xs` with `ys` in `l`,

```
replaceWith :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
replaceWith xs ys l = map (\x -> if x == xs then ys else x) l
```

In the case here,

```
replaceWith [] [0] [[1, 2, 3],[],[5],[5,6],[]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider that if you have a function `foo` that can transform `[]` to `[0]` and return every other list untouched, `map foo` is the final function that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Change your function with

```
knightPlace n = map (\x -> if null x then [0] else x) $ makeboard n
```

Also consider using pointfree style

```
knightPlace = map (\x -> if null x then [0] else x) . makeboard
```

Comment: Did you try to compile that last function in the comments? You should get a scope error. ;)

Comment: Oh right, I write it while on the train and didn't check it.